# Reading array values inside jsx

Tags: arrays, reactjs

In my Next.JS app,I'm passing an array as a prop to `OrderViewer` component, but when I'm trying to read items of the passes array inside JSX, the following error is thrown.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of null

```
getOrderData = ID => {
  if (ID !== null){
    this.prt.style.display = "block";
    console.log(ID) //This works well.but it doesn't work inside JSX.
    console.log(`type = ${typeof(ID)}`)
  }
}

render(){
  return(
    <div ref={ref => this.prt = ref} onLoad= {this.getOrderData(this.props.orderId)} style={{display: "none"}}>
      <div id="OOP" className="row">
        <div className={"row"}>
          <div className="col-md-1">{this.props.orderId}</div>
          <div className="col-md-10"></div>
          <div className="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing React's state of the OrderView component?

Comment: Yes..it successfully logs array elements in `getOrderData` method but doesn't work inside jsx..

Comment: In getOrderData you are checking if it is not null, but not in jsx part. So it is logged out only if not null...

Comment: when I use `this.props.orderId` it prints the whole array.but doesn't work with indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `Orders` component has `state` as:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    orderId: null
  }
```

you are passing `Orders` component state as props to `OrderViewer` component

```
<OrderViewer orderId={this.state.orderId}/>
```

Inside `OrderViewer` component

```
 // Remember "this.props.orderId" is null 
        getOrderData = ID => {  
            // ID is equal to null so this block is not executed 
            if (ID !== null){
                this.prt.style.display = "block";
                console.log(ID[0]) 
            }
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div ref={ref => this.prt = ref} onLoad= 
        {this.getOrderData(this.props.orderId)} style={{display: "none"}}>
                    <div id="OOP" className="row">
                       <div className={"row"}>
                         // <div className="col-md-1">{this.props.orderId[0] !== null ? this.props.orderId[0] : " "}</div>                              
                                                         // ^^^^^^^^ you are trying to 
                                                         // access "0" index element of null
                            <div className="col-md-10"></div>
                            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
```

So change

```
<div className="col-md-1">{this.props.orderId[0] !== null ? this.props.orderId[0] : " "}</div>
```

to

```
<div className="col-md-1">{this.props.orderId !== null ? this.props.orderId[0] : ""}</div>
```

or

```
<div className="col-md-1">{this.props.orderId && this.props.orderId[0]}</div>
```

Both will check the value of `orderId` and does something.

In second case if `orderId` is null/ false it will not execute code after "&&" operator and if it is not null/ true it will execute the code after "&&" operator i.e. it will return first or "0" index element from the `orderId`.

Comment: But the problem is that `console.log(ID[0])` in `getOrderData` works well though it doesn't work inside JSX..and this still doesn't work

Comment: It prints the order id of the `Order` component.When I use `this.props.orderId` inside JSX, it prints out all the elements inside that div as '001Printed bagsCompleteMAS Holdingsmhc02542017-01-15.'in this case,ID[0] = "001" .

Comment: `orderId` is Array .i.e `orderId = [ 001,Printed bags,Complete, MAS Holdings,mhc0254, 2017-01-15]` i got that but  what about the error is it gone?

Comment: you can use `{this.props.orderId && this.props.orderId[0]}`

Comment: it's my pleasure. Great it worked but the code `{this.props.orderId !== null ? this.props.orderId[0] : "No order"}` and `{this.props.orderId && this.props.orderId[0]}` means same